# How to set a size parameter right in command line python

Tags: python

I'm making a bash script in linux using pixray (image generation tool) library :

This piece of code works :

```
python3 pixray.py --prompt="summer" --iterations=250 --outdir="OUTPUT"
```

But it creates an image that's 256*256px

I've tryed to put a size parameter like this :

```
python3 pixray.py --prompt="summer" --iterations=250 --outdir="OUTPUT" --size=1000,700
```

or even like this :

```
-s = x y
--size x y
--size = x, y
--size=[x,y]
--size="x,y"
--size=["x","y"]
--size=[x,y]
...
```

I got an error saying that --size parameter is expected to have 2 arguments, or general syntax error with some trys

Anyone got a clue ?

Comment: What error message do you have when you do `--size x y` ?

Comment: @Philippe well, i got : process terminated. It's the only one that way